# How to signal EOF of stdin when in mac osx terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, eof

I know that in linux's terminal, it's ctrl+D. I also searched that in OSX's terminal. Someone said it's Control+Q, Control+D,return. But this 3 step command doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: It's just Control-D - the same as on pretty much any version of Unix, Linux, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Just use Ctrl-D, it would do the work in any terminal.