# How to signal EOF on MAC OS X with CLion

Tags: c++, macos, eof, clion

I have recently started to learn C++ and have been following the book Accelerated C++. I am on Chapter 3 and I tried to run the program given in the book. I am working on CLion on my MAC OS. The code is the following :

```
#include "iomanip"
#include "ios"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"

using std::cin; using std::cout;
using std::endl; using std::string;
using std::setprecision; using std::streamsize;
using std::vector; using std::sort;

int main()
{
    // Ask for and read student's name
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello, "<< name << "!"<< endl;

    // Ask for and read mid-term and final grades
    cout << "Please enter your mid-term and final grades: ";
    double midterm_grade, final_grade;
    cin >>midterm_grade >> final_grade;

    // Ask for homework grades
    cout << "Enter all your homework grades, followed by end-of-file";

    vector<double> homework;
    double x;
    //Invariant : Homework contains all homework grades read so far

    while (cin >> x)
    {
        homework.push_back(x);
    }

    // Check that the student entered some homework grade

    typedef vector<double>:: size_type vector_size;
    vector_size size = homework.size();

    if(size == 0)
    {
        cout << "You must enter your grades. Please try again" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
// Sort the grades
    sort(homework.begin(), homework.end());

// Compute the median output grade

    vector_size mid = size/2;
    double median;
    median = size % 2 == 0 ? (homework[mid] + homework[mid-1])/2 : homework[mid];

// Compute and write the final grade

    streamsize prec = cout.precision();
    cout << "Your final grade is :" << setprecision(3) << 0.2*midterm_grade + 0.4*final_grade + 0.4*median<< setprecision(prec) << endl;
    return 0;
    }//
```

The program compiles well and I can enter the name and also the grades. But then when I press Ctrl+D (which is the EOF confirmed from the terminal, also suggested here [How to signal EOF of stdin when in mac osx terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848134/how-to-signal-eof-of-stdin-when-in-mac-osx-terminal)) or Cmd+D (as suggested also).

When I press Ctrl+D, the program just restarts. On pressing Cmd+D, it has some unusual behaviour. It may work sometimes, and other times it doesnt. I have also tried to look in the Preferences-> Keymap but I can't find which parameter to set.

I think I am missing some really basic key settings here. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you click in the "run" window, where the output is written and the input is entered, before pressing the `Ctrl-D` combination? Did you press the keys on an empty line?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I have done that earlier also but I keep on trying combinations. For the same combination, it works sometimes, and other times doesn't. Here are the different cases: Doing on next line, doesn't work. Doing on next line, and "clicking on run window" doesn't work. Leaving a blank space and then doing on next line also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently what worked was sending just "EOF" in the run window and then the program ran every time without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, it is Command(<kbd>⌘</kbd>) + <kbd>D</kbd>. If you are using Windows, it is Control(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Also, if you search "Clion Keymap" (Clion preferences/settings) --> Keymap --> Search EOF and/or look at [Keymap settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xR3T.png), you'll see the default settings.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. With command + D, the process somehow exit.

Comment: EOF on macOS is Ctrl+D, same as Unix.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with the os x with clion. in **Find->action**, disable **run.process.with.pty**, it should work as below:

What you need to do is to press cmd+d in a **new empty line.** In your case,enter the homework grade, in the next new empty line , press cmd+d.